# Convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n +1}}{2n+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

In a textbook it is claimed that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{(-1)^{n +1}}{2n+1}=\frac{-\pi}{4}$   converges. How would I calculate to what it converges?

Is there some formula with which I can let it converge (like you have for power series $ \sum_{0}^{\infty} z^n$ in which $|z|<1$ )?

This is the thinking behind it:

$\arctan(z)= \int{\frac{1}{1+z^2}}dz +\text{Constant}$
$= \int \sum_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n }{z^{2n+2}}dz+\text{Constant}$
$\displaystyle =\dots=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{(-1)^{n +1}}{(2n+1)z^{2n+1}}+\text{Constant}$

Now I want to determine: $\text{Constant}$.
Since I know that $\arctan(1)=\pi/4 +n \pi $, I might use that.
However then I need to know to what the series converges.... And how do I know that?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_series.

Comment: @lhf How do I apply your suggestion?

Comment: I'm not sure what the last sentence should mean. You have $$\frac{1}{1+z^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nz^{2n}$$ for $\lvert z\rvert < 1$, so by integrating, you get $$\arctan z = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}z^{2n+1}.$$ You can find that it converges for $z = \pm 1$ using Leibniz' criterion, and if you're enterprisey, you can show that it converges for all $\lvert z\rvert = 1$ except $z = \pm i$. By Abel, you have $\arctan z$ whenever the series converges.

Comment: @DanielFischer I posed the question differently now, to illustrate my problem more clearly. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Leibnitz is what you are looking for.

Comment: I want to see to what it converges also

Comment: @student It converges to $-\dfrac{\pi}{4}$. It's the series for $-\arctan 1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes indeed, it is the series of $arctan(1)$. However, is there some formula with which I can let it converge (like you have for power series $ \sum_{0}^{\infty} z^n$ in which $|z|<1$ )?

Answer (score 0):

For the convergence use the [Leibniz Criterion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeibnizCriterion.html).

Comment: I want to see to what it converges also

Comment: @student In this case see the [Leibniz formula for $\pi$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_pi)